# Calling view method on timer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have setup a view and I want to cycle the color of some text on that view using a timer. Is there a timer method for a view that gets called (or I can setup to get called) on a regular basis?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an NSTimer with the following method:

```
timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:
```

Look here for further information:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:

Comment: +1: create an NSTimer using `NSTimer *myTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] timerWithTimeInterval:<TIME> target:nil selector:@selector(<A_METHOD>:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`  
Then, in your `dealloc`, release it.

Comment: So would I just add that timer to the view, set it up in viewDidLoad and then add a updateMyTextColor method?

Comment: You can do so, if you know the time after which the event should fire in your viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimer` will work for you as long as you don't require "fine" precision -- like sub-100ms.

Core Animation may work here as well. Are you animating a UILabel or are you rendering the text directly into the view with Core Graphics calls (or OpenGL)?

Comment: I was hoping to animate the color of a UILabel.